# Multiple GROUP and COUNT Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle 11g database with two tables I need to pull, group, and count data from. The data in the tables is:

```
Table 'ED'
|NAME | SSN       | IDG   | IDE | IDD | SPOUSE | CHILD |
========================================================
|John | 111111111 | 12345 | 123 | 0   | FALSE  | FALSE |
|Sue  | 111221111 | 12345 | 123 | 1   | TRUE   | FALSE |
|Joe  | 111331111 | 12345 | 123 | 2   | FALSE  | TRUE  |
|Sam  | 111441111 | 12345 | 321 | 0   | FALSE  | TRUE  |
|Jane | 111551111 | 12345 | 321 | 1   | TRUE   | FALSE |
|Jim  | 111661111 | 12345 | 555 | 0   | FALSE  | TRUE  |
|Zach | 111771111 | 12345 | 555 | 2   | FALSE  | TRUE  |

Table 'EL'
|IDG   | IDE | IDD | FLAG01 | FLAG02 | FLAG03 | FLAG04 |
========================================================
|12345 | 123 | 0   | TRUE   | FALSE  | TRUE   | TRUE   |
|12345 | 123 | 1   | TRUE   | FALSE  | FALSE  | FALSE  |
|12345 | 123 | 2   | TRUE   | TRUE   | TRUE   | TRUE   |
|12345 | 321 | 0   | TRUE   | FALSE  | TRUE   | TRUE   |
|12345 | 321 | 1   | TRUE   | FALSE  | FALSE  | FALSE  |
|12345 | 555 | 0   | TRUE   | FALSE  | TRUE   | TRUE   |
|12345 | 555 | 1   | TRUE   | FALSE  | FALSE  | FALSE  |
```

So the first 3 people are a family, the father, spouse, and child. I need to count all of them as a group "family" under IDG=12345 and IDE=123. The next 2 people are a couple, husband and wife. I need to group them as a "couple". The last 2 people are a father and child so they need to be grouped as "dad-child". The next grouping is a count of each of the above groupings where FLAG01=T then a separate count where FLAG02 is true, and FLAG03 is true and FLAG04 is true. So the desired output would be:

```
FLAG01=T:
Family: 3
Couple: 2
Dad-Child: 2

FLAG02=T:
Family: 1
Couple: 0
Dad-Child: 0

FLAG03=T:
Family: 2
Couple: 1
Dad-Child: 1

FLAG04=T:
Family: 2
Couple: 1
Dad-Child: 1
```

I know there must be a join on the two tables for the IDG and IDE fields but I'm not sure how to group by the "family", "couple", "dad-child" categories and then count the numbers based on the flags being true or false. I appreciate any and all assistance!

Comment: Your desired output doesn't quite make sense.  Can you put it in a table format, with well-defined columns?  I am expecting three rows based on your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, of course if I understood correctly your problem

```
SELECT COUNT(EL.FLAG01), COUNT(EL.FLAG02), COUNT(EL.FLAG03), COUNT(EL.FLAG04), ED.IDE 
FROM ED
INNER JOIN EL on ED.IDE=EL.IDE
GROUP BY ED.IDE
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't group them by the family/couple/dad-child categories. The only way to determine that grouping is based on the SPOUSE/CHILD flags being set to true. So the IDE is a unique number within the IDG number/grouping but I need a way to calculate if they should be grouped as Family/Couple/Dad-Child.

Answer (score 0):

looking to you data and based  on you explanation you could retrieve the value you need  using some aggregation function 
(assuming TRUE and FALSE are string otherwise  .. remove quotes in query)

```
select IDG
  , IDE
  , count(*)
  , case when max(spouse) = 'TRUE' AND max(child) = 'FALSE' then 'Couple'
         when max(spouse) = 'TRUE' AND max(child) = 'TRUE' then 'Family'
         when max(spouse) = 'FALSE' AND max(child) = 'TRUE' AND count(*)>1 then dad-child
         END type_of_ralation
FROM ED
group by IDG , IDE
```